# How do you generate a Ripple address and secret using the ripple-lib javascript library?

Tags: ripple, ripple-api

The ripple client application can generate new accounts using the elliptic curve algorithm. Is there a high-level function to perform this task?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a nice script written by you.
https://github.com/stevenzeiler/ripple-wallet

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script for it. It generates a secret and an address, and with using library ripple-keypairs you can get private and public keys too.

```
'use strict';
const RippleAPI = require('ripple-lib').RippleAPI;
var test_server = 'wss://s2.ripple.com';
var keypairs = require('ripple-keypairs');
const api = new RippleAPI({
    server: test_server // Public rippled server
});
api.connect().then(() => { 
    /* begin custom code ------------------------------------ */
    return api.generateAddress();
}).then(address_info => {
    console.log("Secret: " + address_info.secret);
    console.log("Address: " + address_info.address);
    var keypair = keypairs.deriveKeypair(address_info.secret);
    var privateKey = keypair.privateKey;
    console.log("Private key: " + privateKey);
    var publicKey = keypair.publicKey;
    console.log("Public key: " + publicKey);
    var address = keypairs.deriveAddress(keypair.publicKey);
    console.log("Address: " + address);
    /* end custom code -------------------------------------- */
}).then(() => {
    return api.disconnect();
}).then(() => {
    console.log('done and disconnected.');
}).catch(console.error);
```

Good luck =)